# Saving a function in a variable in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I am very new to solidity and stack exchange as well.
I am trying to use the date time api from https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime/tree/master/contracts. 
What getYear(date) does is that it takes an argument date and returns the year of the date. I am trying to save the returned value of getYear() to a variable requiredYear like I do in Java or C++. The truffle compiler is giving me other errors so I cannot tell whether this is correct, but I was also not able to find any documentation about it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 uint16 requiredYear = getYear(uint dateStampOfMileStone) constant returns (uint16);
```

Comment: If you have a working example in either one of these two languages, then you can probably see that it looks more or less like this: `uint16 requiredYear = getYear(x);`, where `x` is a constant or an expression.

Comment: @goodvibration thank you for the response. I changed it the way you wrote it, but I'm getting an error "ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier" on that line. My code reads `uint16 requiredYear = getYear(uint dateStampOfMileStone);` and the error points to `dateStampOfMileStone'

Comment: That's NOT how I wrote it!!!

Comment: All I did is plug in `unit dateStampOfMileStone` in x

Comment: `like I do in Java or C++` - is that how you really do it in Java or C++???

Answer (score 1):

First of all, saving a function in a variable in solidity is not possible currently. May be you try to use like JavaScript:

`var func = function(value){
     returns value + 1;
}`

The next thing is, from the comment section, I saw you used

`uint16 requiredYear = getYear(uint dateStampOfMileStone);`

You should use if you want to call the function:

`uint16 requiredYear = getYear(dateStampOfMileStone);`

Hope it will help you.